# Formatting date in mongojs and angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, date

I've a mongo db collection as below.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57048f2f60b18f8e186e65b6"
    },
    "ID": 1,
    "Room_ID": 303,
    "StartTime": "2016-03-12T11:00:00Z",
    "EndTime": "2016-03-12T12:00:00Z",
    "Login_ID": "ABCDE"
}
```

I'm using `db.collection.find()` query to fetch the results. I am trying to display the date in two parts 1. `DD-MM-YY` and 2. `HH-MM-SS`. 
I've two ideas for this. 1. Get the date in the desired format from `collection.find()` command or 2. After fetching the records into cursor, parse it in angularjs code to separate date and time values.

I've tried the [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) of mongodb but couldn't get the results. In fact I am confused with it.

```
db.RoomReservation.aggregate({ $project: {"Login_ID": "ABCDE", dt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$StartTime"}}}});
assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
        "code" : 16006,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
```

Can someone please help me in getting the output of `collection.find()` in the following format

```
Room_ID, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Login_ID
303, 2016-03-12, 11:00, 12:00, ABCDE
```

Comment: This is for MongoDB versions 3.0 or higher. What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using `3.2.4` version

Comment: you should leave date formatting to UI layer. There are capable libraries like Moment.js to display the date in any desired formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply parse your date in angular part using filters , if you want ..

```
     <span>{{ | date:'dd-MM-yyyy @ HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>
```

you can refer for more date options [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Thank you very much for the easy work around. It helped me, though I had to figure out solution the timezone issue. :)